# Can't access an smb share on a machine running Windows 10 after upgrade to version 1709

Tags: macos, windows-10, smb

With the recent update to Windows 10 Version 1709, I cannot mount a shared folder from my Mac system via SMB anymore. According to Microsoft, the update 1709 finally [removed the support of SMBv1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-windows-10-and-windows-server-version-1709) and only accepts requests using SMBv2 or higher. I suspect that this is the reason why I cannot access my shared drive anymore, because the problem has been occurring exactly since I upgraded the Windows system.

Now, here is my question to the community:
What can I do to still access the shared drive via SMB? I tried to enforce the use of SMBv2 protocol according to the suggestions on [this SO post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285516), to no avail. I'm a bit stuck here for my understanding of the SMB protocol is pretty limited.

Details:

- The systems run MacOS 10.11.6 and Windows 10 v1709
- I ensured that the Windows system is accessible (ping responds)
- I try to mount the target drive using two ways:

  - via Finder: ⌘+K shortcut, `smb://server-name/folder`
  - using the command: `mount_smbfs //user@address/folder ./mount-point`

Both approaches time out. Let me know if you need additional information about the systems involved.

Comment: IIRC without SMBv1 you might be missing the 'discovery' portion, and depending on your DNS setup you might be unable to resolve hostnames. I'm not too sure about MacOS though. Have you tried connecting by IP address rather than hostname?

Comment: Also, the upgrade shouldn't have disabled SMBv1 for existing systems; only for new installs. You can check and toggle this option through the Windows Features dialog. (It is recommended to disable SMBv1 but currently known bugs have been patched.)

Comment: @Bob: Many thanks for your hints. Regarding the first comment: Yes, I also tried to connect with the IP address directly, but with no effect. Regarding the second comment: Indeed, the SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support is enabled. Hmm. So maybe I'm on the wrong track to suspect SMB protocols for causing the problems?

Comment: It appears like that’s the case

Comment: Indeed, temporarily disabling the firewall lets me connect to the device!

Comment: @normanius I assume you mean the Windows firewall? This can be because you've either not correctly set the file sharing settings (in "Advanced sharing settings") for your network profile, or you're on the wrong network profile (e.g. your current network is detected as public vs domain vs private). The sharing settings are applied per-profile and the profile can be toggled under the "make this PC discoverable" option under Settings => Network & Internet => Ethernet/Wi-Fi.

Comment: mounting the drive using `cifs://server-name/folder` should use smb1.  `smb://...` uses smb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if my problem is indeed related to the recent upgrade of Windows 10 or a change in how my workstation is embedded in the network of my workplace, but I was able to fix my issue by editing the "SMB-in" default setting for the accepted remote addresses from "Local subnet" to "Any" (or anything that makes sense or is safe enough for your setup).

The setting can be found here: Control Panel => System and Security => Windows Defender Firewall => Advanced => Inbound Rules => File and Printer Sharing (SMB-in)

I could not verify if this setting was changed after the update or not. But for sure it was not an issue with incompatible SMB protocols on the client side.